# Where does the "privacy protection password" come from?

Tags: lock-screens, security, anti-theft

I wanted to insert a second sim card in my Umi phone.
From then onwards, it always asks me for this 'privacy protection password'.
I can only insert numbers, not letters... so I'm very puzzled about what this does.

I have all pin, puk, passwords of everything in a book here. But whatever pin I try it keeps failing.
Can anyone help me please?

Is this from the Prey app? Or from Android itself? Can I reset it somewhere witha  password online on the web?

Comment: did you set up an anti-theft password or someone else for your device?